# Integrating GC Log with Logback

Tags: java, garbage-collection, logback

I want to integrate GC log with my own http based Logger to avoid file based logging.
I followed : http://www.fasterj.com/articles/gcnotifs.shtml article. From JDk 7 onward we can add our own listener on GC event which is working fine. But I want my gc logs to printed in the same way as we log it earlier.

Like below.

```
    2019-11-04T10:12:33.754+0000: 3.199: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
    Desired survivor size 50331648 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
    , 0.0300627 secs]
       [Parallel Time: 18.2 ms, GC Workers: 8]
          [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 3198.9, Avg: 3198.9, Max: 3199.0, Diff: 0.1]
          [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.7, Avg: 2.7, Max: 11.7, Diff: 11.0, Sum: 21.3]
          [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
             [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0, Diff: 0, Sum: 0]
          [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
          [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.6, Max: 2.6, Diff: 2.6, Sum: 4.5]
          [Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.8, Avg: 9.9, Max: 16.1, Diff: 15.3, Sum: 79.4]
          [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 4.8, Max: 5.6, Diff: 5.6, Sum: 38.6]
             [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 8]
          [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
          [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 17.9, Avg: 18.0, Max: 18.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 143.9]
          [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 3216.9, Avg: 3216.9, Max: 3217.0, Diff: 0.1]
       [Code Root Fixup: 0.9 ms]
       [Code Root Purge: 0.1 ms]
       [Clear CT: 0.2 ms]
       [Other: 10.8 ms]
```

So I am from the notification I am able to print :

```
    end of minor GC: - 1342 ParNew (from Allocation Failure) 26 milliseconds; start-end times 67212728-67212754
    end of minor GC: - 1343 ParNew (from Allocation Failure) 28 milliseconds; start-end times 68412633-68412661
    end of major GC: - 54 ConcurrentMarkSweep (from System.gc()) 147 milliseconds; start-end times 68563369-68563516
    end of minor GC: - 1344 ParNew (from Allocation Failure) 109 milliseconds; start-end times 70212722-70212831
    end of minor GC: - 1345 ParNew (from Allocation Failure) 39 milliseconds; start-end times 71413175-71413214
    end of minor GC: - 1346 ParNew (from Allocation Failure) 42 milliseconds; start-end times 72013977-72014019
```

```
    public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
          //get the information associated with this notification
          //get all the info and pretty print it
          GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo info = GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.from((CompositeData) notification.getUserData());
          LOG.info(info.getGcAction() + ": - " + info.getGcInfo().getId()+ " " + info.getGcName() + " (from " + info.getGcCause()+") "+info.getGcInfo().getDuration() + " milliseconds; start-end times " + info.getGcInfo().getStartTime()+ "-" + info.getGcInfo().getEndTime());
        }
```

Comment: So what is your issue? How to get the GC log entry sent to the HTTP appender? For you get it formatted correctly? Edit the question and show us what you've done so far, and explain exactly how it is not doing what you want.

Comment: It is impossible. GC notifications do not have all detail available in text logs.

Comment: @Andreas i have edited the Question to show how I am printing the information.